# Increase width and decrease size of ribbon

Tags: css

I have the following code that I took from http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-ribbon-with-borders

The HTML Code is:

```
<div id="ribbon">

<div class="inset"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="left_corner"></div>
    <div class="right_corner"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS Code is:

```
#ribbon {
width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 margin: 0px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#ribbon .inset {
width: 200px;
 height: 55px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -50px;
 left: -10px;
 z-index: 5;

-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;

background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#ribbon .container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 250px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-left: 1px solid #631a15;
 border-right: 1px solid #631a15;
}

#ribbon .base {
 height: 200px;
 width: 100px;

background: rgb(199,59,60);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%, rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(199,59,60,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(184,32,31,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c73b3c', endColorstr='#b8201f',GradientType=0 );

 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}

#ribbon .base:after {
 content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
 width: 86px;
left: 6px;
 height: 242px;
 border-left: 1px dashed #631a15;
border-right: 1px dashed #631a15;
}

#ribbon .base:before {
 content: '';
position: absolute;
 top: 0;
width: 86px;
 left: 7px;
height: 242px;
 border-left: 1px dashed #da5050;
border-right: 1px dashed #da5050;
}

#ribbon .left_corner {
 width: 100px;
height: 100px;
 background: #b8201f;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
left: -50px;
 z-index: 1;

-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#ribbon .right_corner {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
 background: #b8201f;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
right: -50px;
 z-index: 1;

-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I want to increase the width (to 250px) and decrease the height (to 140px) of the ribbon.

how can i do this?

i am still studying CSS.
I also want to insert an image on top of the ribbon that is formed by the above coding.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go bro :) Check the **[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/d9cKF/3/)** 
**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/d9cKF/4/)**

```
#ribbon .base {
  height: 140px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Have changed the `.left_arrow` and `.right_arrow` values to make it fit. Check it on Fiddle and ask me if you want any clarifications.

Comment: Dihraj Sir, I have left you a comment on your site. Please Acknowledge.

Comment: I will be available after 9 pm. Meanwhile, you can email me the details :)

Answer (score 1):

Width 250px and height 140px is done..
**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9cKF/)**
**HTML**

```
<div id="ribbon">
    <div class="inset"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="base"></div>
        <div class="left_corner"></div>
        <div class="right_corner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#ribbon {
    width: 350px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ribbon .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #631a15;
    border-right: 1px solid #631a15;
}

#ribbon .base {
    height: 80px;
    width: 250px;

    background: rgb(99,59,60);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%, rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(199,59,60,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(184,32,31,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(199,59,60,1) 0%,rgba(184,32,31,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c73b3c', endColorstr='#b8201f',GradientType=0 );

    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#ribbon .base:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 234px;
    left: 6px;
    height: 132px;
    border-left: 1px dashed #631a15;
    border-right: 1px dashed #631a15;
}

#ribbon .base:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 234px;
    left: 7px;
    height: 132px;
    border-left: 1px dashed #da5050;
    border-right: 1px dashed #da5050;
}

#ribbon .left_corner {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #b8201f;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: -45px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(50deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(50deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(50deg);
    transform: rotate(145deg);
}

#ribbon .right_corner {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #b8201f;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: -45px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}

#ribbon .inset {
    width: 400px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 5;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Sir the ribbon that is formed i want to insert an image on top of it, so that the ribbon becomes the background of the image.

Also, I want the width of the red area to be 250px and height of the red area to be 140px.

what u have done has not increased the width or decreased the height.

Comment: actually bhavik bhai mujhe mere client ne kaha hai ki use ek ribbon chaiye on top of the navigation bar and us ribbon ke uppar uski company ka logo.

aapne jo kiya hai na usse ribbon sirf shift hui hai, par mujhe ribbon chaudi aur height me nati chaiye.

Please help karo.

Comment: **[Even another better alternate](http://jsfiddle.net/d9cKF/2/)** Besides of all this the structure won't go perfect as ribbon is always more longer than its width... And what you want is completely opposite